# Is possible determine the range of the random var with the given information?

Tags: probability

I have this statement:

> You have a bag with $m$ cards of the same shape and size, of which $p$ are
> red and the rest are blue, with $0 < p < m$. The experiment is performed
> to extract $n$ cards from the bag, one after the other and  without
> replacement. The random variable $X$ is defined as the
> number of red cards obtained. The range of $X$ can be determined if it
> is known:
>
> $i)$ Value of $p$
>
> $ii)$ Value of $n$

My attempt was:

With $i)$ i can't determine the range since the amount of red cards does not determine the amount of cards extracted.

With $ii)$ i can't determine the range since i don't have the numbers of red cards.

With $i), ii)$ together i have this cases:

When $n > p$, i can extract a maximum of $p$ red carts, that is: $[....,p]$, but i don't know the minimum. Per example, if $m = 11, n = 5, p = 7, b = 4$, where $b$ are blue cards. The minimum value of $X$ will be $1$, that is $4$ blue cars and $1$ red card, but if $b = 5$, the minimum value of $X$ is $0$.

When $n < p$, i cant extract a maximum of $n$ red carts, that is: $[...., n]$ but i don't know the minimum.

So my answer is that, additional information is needed(that is the numbers of total cards $m$)

But according to the guide the correct answer is $i), ii)$ together. So, what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: I believe m is a fixed constant and we can treat it as a known one (so you know b in every of those cases)

Comment: And if i believe that $m$ isn't fixed? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as $m\ge n$, the solution is $min(n,p)$, which is known if you know $i)$ and $ii)$.  If you wish to determine probabilities for $X$, the you will need to know $m$.

Comment: So, what is wrong with my development? Can you explain more please

Comment: I thought you were asking for the maximum for the range, not both the min and max.  Your analysis is correct, i.e. the max is what we both described, but the min cannot be obtained without knowing m.

Comment: Ok, many thanks.

Comment: The min for red can be gotten from the max of blue=min(m-p,n), so the min of red =n-min(m-p,n).  Obviously you need to know m.